The control add-in on control PDFViewer on page PDF Viewer has not been instantiated
I have a problem with the pdf preview control,
when I edit something on a page that does not have the pdf preview, it gives me an error message "The control add-in on control PDFViewer on page PDF Viewer has not been instantiated.". The pdf preview I have in the list below the two page preview only has its settings and trigger
pageextension 80003 IllegalMonitoringPDFViewer extends " Illegal Monitoring "
{
    layout
    {
        addfirst(factboxes)
        {
            part(PDFViewerMatrix; "PDFV PDF Viewer Factbox")
            {
                ApplicationArea = All;
                Visible = VisiblePDF;
            }
        }
    }
    var
        VisiblePDF: Boolean;

    trigger OnAfterGetRecord()
    var
        DocumentAttachment: Record "Document Attachment";
        RecId: Integer;
        RecRef: RecordRef;
    begin
        VisiblePDF := false;
        RecRef.Open(Database::"illegal trade ");
        RecId := RecRef.Number();
        DocumentAttachment.Reset();
        DocumentAttachment.SetFilter("Table ID", Format(RecId));
        DocumentAttachment.SetFilter("No.", Rec."No.");
        if DocumentAttachment.FindLast() then
            VisiblePDF := true
        else
            VisiblePDF := false;
    end;

    trigger OnAfterGetCurrRecord()
    var
        DocumentAttachment: Record "Document Attachment";
        RecId: Integer;
        RecRef: RecordRef;
    begin
        VisiblePDF := false;
        RecRef.Open(Database::"illegal trade ");
        RecId := RecRef.Number();
        DocumentAttachment.Reset();
        DocumentAttachment.SetFilter("Table ID", Format(RecId));
        DocumentAttachment.SetFilter("No.", Rec."No.");
        if DocumentAttachment.FindLast() then begin
            VisiblePDF := true;
            CurrPage.PDFViewerMatrix.Page.setrecord(DocumentAttachment);
        end else
            VisiblePDF := false;

    end;


}


in the variable pdfText there is a reference to the attachment
page 80001 "PDFV PDF Viewer Factbox"
{

    Caption = 'PDF Viewer';
    PageType = CardPart;
    SourceTable = "Document Attachment";
    DeleteAllowed = false;
    InsertAllowed = false;
    LinksAllowed = false;


    layout
    {
        area(content)
        {
            group(General)
            {
                ShowCaption = false;
                usercontrol(PDFViewer; "PDFV PDF Viewer")
                {
                    ApplicationArea = All;

                    trigger ControlAddinReady()
                    begin
                        SetPDFDocument(Rec);
                    end;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    procedure setrecord(var DocumentAtt: Record "Document Attachment")
    begin

        SetPDFDocument(DocumentAtt);
        CurrPage.Update(false);
    end;

    local procedure SetPDFDocument(var DocumentAttachment: Record "Document Attachment")
    var
        PDFAsTxt: Text;
    begin
        CurrPage.PDFViewer.LoadPDF(PDFAsTxt, true);
    end;
}

when editing this page the problem occurs no matter what I edit

page 50016 "Illegal announcement form"
{
    Caption = 'Announcement form';
    PageType = Card;
    SourceTable = "illegal trade ";
    RefreshOnActivate = false;
    layout
    {}
}

Do you have any ideas on how this problem could be solved ?

the example you provided uses the PDFViewer of Volodymyr Dvernytskyi's GitHub repository: https://github.com/Drakonian/bc-pdf-viewer if I'm not mistaken. (Shout outs to Volodymyr!)
In the mentioned repo a custom table is used to store the PDFs.
We are now trying to replace the custom tables by the "Document Attachment" table, correct?
Copying the SetPDFDocument() procedure from the page 80004 "PDFV PDFViewerDocAttachament" might be a good starting point:
local procedure SetPDFDocument()
var
    Base64Convert: Codeunit "Base64 Convert";
    TempBlob: Codeunit "Temp Blob";
    InStreamVar: InStream;
    OutStreamVar: OutStream;
    PDFAsTxt: Text;
begin
    CurrPage.PDFViewer.SetVisible(Rec."Document Reference ID".HasValue());
    if not Rec."Document Reference ID".HasValue() then
        exit;

    TempBlob.CreateInStream(InStreamVar);
    TempBlob.CreateOutStream(OutStreamVar);
    Rec."Document Reference ID".ExportStream(OutStreamVar);

    PDFAsTxt := Base64Convert.ToBase64(InStreamVar);

    CurrPage.PDFViewer.LoadPDF(PDFAsTxt, true);
end;

Rec is based on the SourceTable = "Document Attachment". It's up to us to change this procedure to fit our own needs. Notice that the "Document Attachment" table's PK is combined by 5 table fields: Table ID, No., Attachment Document Type, Line No. and ID.
Focusing on your pageextension 80003 IllegalMonitoringPDFViewer, the line CurrPage.PDFViewerMatrix.Page.setrecord(DocumentAttachment); would not work in that repo by default as the underlying logic in the "PDFV PDF Viewer Matrix" uses the custom pdf storage table. I assume you already changed that, which leaves open the question of why it doesn't work.
Worked for me in a v24.3 w1 bc container using the PDFViewer of the mentioned repo. Did not receive the error message: "The control add-in on control PDFViewer on page PDF Viewer has not been instantiated." and instead the content of the uploaded PDF (into "Document Attachment" table) is displayed in the customer list extension.

Thank you very much @ChristianBraeunlich for your help, it turns out that the problem occurs when the pdf preview does not load on the page with the list of illegal revs, so that when the preview did not load the control could not bottom out and load the preview because it was not on that page and therefore an error was returned. If you have an idea how this could be secured, I am interested in a solution. But for the moment the pdf preview works, you just have to be patient to load the preview and only edit the illegal turnover.
